Curious interchange of the order of summation
Usually interchanging the order of summation requires $\sum_n\sum_m|a_{n,m}|<\infty$. Unfortunately, I don't have this condition on my hands. Only conditions I have are:
$$\sum_n\left|\sum_m a_{n,m}\right|<\infty\quad \sum_m\left|\sum_n a_{n,m}\right|<\infty$$
Would these be sufficient for this specific rearrangement of the order of summation (switching the $n$- and $m$-sum)?
I tried using the dominated convergence theoreom (notation from the wikipedia): if we set $f_n(m):=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k,m}$ we obtain our claim by applying the theorem, after proving that there exists $g$ such that $|f_n|<g$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. As summing $f_n(m)$ over $m$ is possible, $|f_n(m)|$ is bounded in $m$, i.e. $f_n$ is a bounded function. I'm not sure if there is a way to proceed (or a possible counterexample).
Thank you!

No, the conditions are not enough.
Take $a_{n,m} = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } n=m\\
-1 & \text{ if } n=m+1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

@mertunsal Are you sure about that, as far as I can see the sum is equal to either zero either 1 so it should be integrable

@mertunsal What are you talking about? Both $\sum_n\left|\sum_m a_{n,m}\right|$ and $\sum_m\left|\sum_n a_{n,m}\right|$ exists and are finite.

I must have read something wrong, yeah you are right
